# Identifying different default arguments for different versions of function templates

Tags: c++, templates

First I have a function template

```
template<typename S>
void foo(const S & s, int a = 1, double b = 2)
```

Then I want to provide specialized implementations given `S` is a STL container. Specially, I want to provide different default arguments.

Since partial function template specialization is not allowed in C++, I just overload `foo`. Say

```
template<typename T>
void foo(const vector<T> & s, int a = 3, double b = 4)
```

Everything fine and well at this point.

Now I want to write a function template `partial_foo`, which accepts only one parameter `double b = 6`, and then let compiler decide the default argument for `a`, depending on which version of `foo` it calls. *Note that `b` is after `a` in the call signature of `foo`.*

```
template<typename S>
foo_partial(const S & s, double b = 6)
```

Ideally, `foo_partial(int)` would have a default argument `int a = 1` while `foo_partial(vector<int>())` would have a default argument `int a = 3`.

**My question is: Can I do this (i.e. how to implement `foo_partial`), or is there any workaround, given the design of `foo`?**

For a concrete example, please consider

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template<typename S>
void foo(const S & s, int a = 1, double b = 2)
{
    printf("foo(S) with a = %d, b = %.0f\n", a, b);
}

template<typename T>
void foo(const vector<T> & t, int a = 3, double b = 4)
{
    printf("foo(vector<T>) with a = %d, b = %.0f\n", a, b);
}

template<typename S>
void foo_partial(const S & s, double b = 6)
{
    // how to implement foo_partial so that ____ corresponds to
    // the default argument in the proper version of foo?
    int ____ = 5;
    foo(s, ____, b);
}

int main()
{
    foo_partial(0);
    foo_partial(vector<int>());
}
```

The output is

```
foo(S) with a = 5, b = 6
foo(vector<T>) with a = 5, b = 6
```

**My question is equivalent to: Is there anything or any workaround that I can do with the design of `foo_partial` so that the output would be**

```
foo(vector) with a = 1, b = 6
foo(forward_list) with a = 3, b = 6
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't include `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` it's non standard and wont work on most platforms.

`using namespace std` is also not recommended as it can cause conflicts between future standard additions and your own code.

One way to solve your problem would be to move your default arguments to a template class with specialisations:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using std::vector;

template <typename S>
struct defaults
{
    static constexpr int a = 1;
    static constexpr double b = 2;
};

template <typename T>
struct defaults<vector<T>>
{
    static constexpr int a = 3;
    static constexpr double b = 4;
};

template<typename S>
void foo(const S & s, int a = defaults<S>::a, double b = defaults<S>::b)
{
    printf("foo(S) with a = %d, b = %.0f\n", a, b);
}

template<typename T>
void foo(const vector<T> & t, int a = defaults<vector<T>>::a, double b = defaults<vector<T>>::b)
{
    printf("foo(vector<T>) with a = %d, b = %.0f\n", a, b);
}

template<typename S>
void foo_partial(const S & s, double b = 6)
{
    foo(s, defaults<S>::a, b);
}

int main()
{
    foo_partial(0);
    foo_partial(vector<int>());
}
```

If you are only specialising `foo` to change the default arguments then the function overloads are no longer required.

Comment: Thanks, I think this could be one approach! And I admit the first two lines in my example are very bad practice. Thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also employ so-called **named parameter idiom**, which is kind-of more generic and scalable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T> class Foo {
  int a_; double b_; const T& value_;
public:
  Foo(const T& value) : value_(value), a_(1), b_(2.0) { }
  Foo& set_a(int a) { a_ = a; return *this; }
  Foo& set_b(double b) { b_ = b; return *this; }
  void operator()() { std::cout << "foo(T) with a = " << a_ << " and b = " << b_ << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T> class Foo<std::vector<T>> {
  int a_; double b_; const std::vector<T>& value_;
public:
  Foo(const std::vector<T>& value) : value_(value), a_(3), b_(4.0) { }
  Foo& set_a(int a) { a_ = a; return *this; }
  Foo& set_b(double b) { b_ = b; return *this; }
  void operator()() { std::cout << "foo(std::vector<T>) with a = " << a_ << " and b = " << b_ << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T>
void foo_partial(const T& value, double b = 6) { Foo<T>(value).set_b(b)(); }

int main() {
  foo_partial(0);
  foo_partial(std::vector<int>{});
}
```

Which prints out:

```
foo(T) with a = 1 and b = 6    
foo(std::vector<T>) with a = 3 and b = 6
```